# React export constants

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I don't get why the following approach doesn't work:

**constants.js**

```
import { createConstants } from '../utils';

export default createConstants(
    'LOGIN_REQUEST',
    'LOGIN_SUCCESS',
    'LOGIN_FAILURE',
    'LOGOUT',
    'FETCH_DATA_REQUEST',
    'RECEIVE_DATA'
);
```

**utils.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export function createConstants(...constants) {
    return constants.reduce((acc, constant) => {
        acc[constant] = constant;
        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

Next I want to import LOGIN_REQUEST for example as a redux action.

```
import { LOGIN_REQUEST, LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_FAILURE, LOGOUT } from '../constants';
```

But I'm getting `undefined` each time for all imported constants. It works only when I'm defining like this:

```
export const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'LOGIN_REQUEST';
```

Maybe somebody has some ideas?

Comment: It would probably work if you wrote `module.exports = createConstants(...)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first approach is called a `default export`. It doesn't work because the syntax you're using is not correct.

From the [MDN `export` entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export), that's how you write a `default export`:

```js
// module "my-module.js"
export default function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}
```

Your second approach is called `named export` and it works because it has the right syntax. Again from MDN:

```js
export const foo = Math.sqrt(2); // exports a constant
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Export doesn't work like that. You can try something like:

```
import allConstants from '../constants';
```

Then use a constant like:

```
allConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST
```